# Drupal 7 - calling jquery function when a node load

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-nodes

I have a node (alias is 'help', node id is 12) and would like to call a jquery function when this node loads.

If it helps the node has it's own page template page--node--12.tpl.php

Answer (score 0):

In your theme's template.php file you want to use the preprocess hook called when the node loads - `hook_preprocess_node`.

Check for the node id in here and then use `drupal_add_js()` to add your jQuery code.

Comment: this would work but was looking to do something after the page loads as I need access to the content. Can I pass the node id parameter to jquery

Comment: You can use the node id in the preprocess hook. You can add it to the jQuery here.